# Default timeout configuration file for composer

Tags: php, laravel-4, vagrant, composer-php

Iv been searching all over the internet and i cant seem to find any help as to where my composers configuration file is saved to. Basically what I'm trying to do is change the `COMPOSER_PROCESS_TIMEOUT=300` to `COMPOSER_PROCESS_TIMEOUT=2000` as explained in this [blog post](http://www.papayasoft.com/2013/08/22/composer-process-timeout-when-fetching-large-repositories/). I'm currently running a vagrant box virtual Ubuntu server setup.
Does anyone know where i am to find this file in my Ubuntu server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer to my question after some more digging, in order to update the process timeout for composer simply invoke this command `composer config --global process-timeout 2000` .Looks like a new day did me well, For all those wondering where the link to this answer comes from its found on [this site](http://www.craftitonline.com/2013/12/composer-the-latest-of-our-alpha-symfony2-tricks/).